# JavaScript for() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I wanted to multiple form inside body using only jQuery. 
Where am I making mistake?

I'm new to jQuery and JS.

This is my [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zusisomi/1/edit)

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
  var input = $('<input>', {
    value :'add here'
  }).appendTo('body');

  var button = $('<button>',{
    text:'click'
  }).appendTo('body');

  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    input[i].appendTo('body');
  }
})();
```

Comment: http://jsbin.com/zusisomi/5/edit check this. it's easy way to append.

Comment: why do people downvote this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` is a jQuery object, which is array like, so you can access `[i]` on it.

The values inside it as DOM elements, not jQuery objects, so they don't have `appendTo` properties.

It also only contains a single element, so when `i` is 1 or higher, there is nothing to append.

If you want to copy the element 10 times, then use `.clone()` not `[i]`.

Comment: actually really not understand thanx anyway!